# AWS S3 Granting Access to entire folder - C#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm looking for creative ways to solve a difficult problem. And I need to do this via C# code only, no website configurations.

My users upload a "package" of files. These are **usually** HTML files with relative paths to images and other resources. Currently I store these in a folder in an S3 bucket. So far there is no problem.

The problem appears when I need to serve this file back to the client. I need a way to give them access to the HTML file for X amount of time while also keeping the integrity of the URL links.

For instance - File.html has a reference to fish.png -

```html
<img src="fish.png"/>
```

If I grant them access to File.html the fish image is broken because they do not have access to "fish.png". If I grant them access to both the link is still broken because the src doesn't have the security token. I've even tried granting access to the folder and both files but still the image is broken. I also can't download the contents because that would defeat the purpose of only having the resource available for X amount of time.

I hope my problem is clear. I am very new at S3 development in general. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT** - I wanted to add that modifying the HTML document links is not an option. They don't always upload HTML, it could be flash files or other file types. I need the document links references to be maintained.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to accomplish.  If the client uploads a bunch of files, is only that client allowed to access them?  When you say you they can only be accessible for a certain amount of time, what happens after that?

Comment: @chris - The client uploads files that are part of a product being sold to the public. It's the access to files via the public that we want to put a timer on and protect the assets. If the timer runs out we want them to get a file not found or an access denied. Anything besides gaining access to the files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first figure out why if they have access to the entire folder, that it doesn't work.

If they have access to the folder, and both files are in that folder and the link to the image has no path, it should work. Until you get that use-case solved, getting the time-based url's working is a non-starter.

You may want to make sure the capitalization is correct  - it matters in s3, whereas if you are used to running in IIS it usually doesn't.

Comment: I have figured out how to grant access to the folder and by making the items inside the folder public I was able to get the html file to display correctly showing the image. The issue now is that any direct links to the html file do not expire because the item is public. Even if the folder permissions expire the items are still accessible. I think I am probably going about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

One potential way to do this would be to make the IMAGE files public, and make the HTML files "signed urls". You can set an expiry time on the signed urls that reference the image files. The image files obviously wouldnt expire, but the access to HTML files that reference the image files WOULD expire.

Not the prettiest solution, but the problem isnt very pretty either. ;-)

You can read more about Pre-Signed URLS here: [Generate a Pre-signed Object URL using AWS SDK for .NET](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html)

Comment: Hey thanks Jim. I came to the same conclusion... however this isn't good for our users as they might be linking to videos as well as images and they don't want their content able to be linked afterwords. Right now I am looking into CloudFront as a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill but I think it would work.

When a user requests the file, you copy the file and any files referenced in the file to a public area (perhaps in a directory using a GUID as a name so it's not easily guessable by other users).

Then when the time has expired you can simply delete the new directory.

Comment: I had thought about that, but it kind of defeats the purpose of using AWS or CloudFront. And if I did that that approach we would need to store files ourselves which we simply don't have the space to do. There are a lot of clients with a huge number of resources (files). Thank you for the idea though